# Rails using private and protected methods in a Service object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, service-object

I'm trying to move some business logic out of one of my controllers, `StoreController` and into a new `Store::CreateService` service object. Learning about services recently, it doesn't seem to be much of an established pattern for implementing them. I'm running into an error trying to call a protected method. I can obviously move the logic from those protected methods directly into `execute` but my understanding was that this should be okay to Rails.

```
undefined local variable or method `find_and_set_account_id' for #<Store::CreateService:0x00007f832f8928f8>
```

Here is the Service object

```
module Store
  class CreateService < BaseService

    def initialize(user, params)
      @current_user, @params = user, params.dup
    end

    def execute

      @store = Store.new(params)

      @store.creator = current_user

      find_and_set_account_id

      if @store.save
        # Make sure that the user is allowed to use the specified visibility level
        @store.members.create(
          role: "owner",
          user: current_user
        )
      end

      after_create_actions if @store.persisted?

      @store
    end
  end

  protected

    def after_create_actions
      event_service.create_store(@store, current_user)
    end

    def find_and_set_account_id
      loop do
        @store.account_id = SecureRandom.random_number(10**7)
        break unless Store.where(account_id: account_id).exists?
      end
    end
end
```

Comment: Are you running the code in console? From the error, it looks like the method was added after you enter the console, try exit console and go back.

Comment: I'm running it from the `create` action of the `StoreController`. I call the method inside the `create` action like so, `@store = ::Store::CreateService.new(current_user, store_params).execute`

Comment: Don't find anything wrong with the code, please make sure you save the file.

Comment: Thanks @Coco, I've doubled checked that the file is saved.

Comment: Fix the syntax in service, include the method in CreateService

Comment: i suggest you should move your account_id , creation logic in model, and instead of writing **@store** , you should use attr to define objects , which will give you freedom from writing @store everywhere and just use **store** to access that object. good luck.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have an extra `end` after `def execute..end`. That end closes the `CreateService` class. This means your protected methods are defined on the `Store` module.

Hence the missing method.

Comment: you just save me a lot of debugging time! thanks!